# design patterns for persisting state on android app

Tags: java, android

For android I am trying persist state if onDestroy() is called.  I'm wondering what are common design patterns used to do such a thing so that the actual app functionality is decoupled from the persistence functionality?  For example, I have a for loop that iterates through all of the players in the game.  This update happens at the end of each round in the game.  Would it be possible that the app gets destroyed half way through the update?  If that happened, what kind of logic would i need to include to remember which player was updated.

Comment: Take a look at the fragments API

Answer (score 0):

You have two main options for saving state.  If you are concerned with instance variables, then override [Activity.onSaveInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29)  The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state) provides a good sample of how to do this.

For persistent data, you can either store it in SharedPreferences, the SQLite database, or write it to a file.  This article should help you get started: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#SavingPersistentState

Answer (score 0):

Your app can be killed half way during the update if users switch to another app such as receiving a phone call.

Considering such cases, you may need to persist your state in onPause() instead of onDestroy() since onPause() is the last method which is guaranted to be called when your activity is killed by the system.

And in onPause(), you can start a background service to do the update which can give your process higher priority so that it's less likely to be killed by the system when you are doing the update.

See more details in the [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html) and  the [Process](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html) document.

Answer (score 0):

Android is not very nice about killing apps. You may or may not get onPause or onDestory.  You may or may not be able to receive a hook onShutdown of the VM.  Basically your app can die at any time (low memory pressure), user kills it, or etc and you won't get any warning.  Basically it is best practice to assume that you can die at ANY time and store or update critical state as soon as you get it.

Basically I would either make a SQLitedatabase or use shared preferences for this.